Spring Bootでjakarta.validationのエラーをコントローラクラスで検知したい
環境
Spring Boot 3.x
JDK21
SpringbootでRestControllerでバリデーションチェックをしたいと考えています。
jakarta.validation、lombok.Dataをインポートして使用しています。
リクエストボディのDTOを以下のように定義しました。
@Data
public class Person {

    private int id;
    
    @Min(1)
    @Max(100)
    private int val;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime time;

    private boolean isDelete;
 
}

コントローラクラスで以下を定義しました。
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody @Validated Person request, BindingResult result) {
    ★
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       ～～
    }
    ～～
}

valの値が1～100以外の場合はresult.hasErrors()でキャッチできたのですが
timeがフォーマットでない場合や、idで数字以外が指定された場合は、★を通らずに、レスポンス404が返りました。
また、REST APIのリクエストボディにPersonのパラメータ自体が無い場合は
★箇所は通りますがresult.hasErrors()がTRUEになりませんでした。
jakarta.validationを使用して、パラメータが無い場合にエラーと判断する方法はありますか？
またコントローラクラスで定義しているメソッド内でエラーとしてフォーマット違いを検知することはできますか？

挙がっている例だと 404 ではなく 400 が返るはずですが、その場合は Controller にメソッド @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class) public void handleException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) { ... } を定義しておけば捕捉できるはずです。もしこのメソッドが呼ばれない場合は @ExceptionHandler アノテーションの引数を変更する必要があるかも知れません。複数の Controller に適用したい場合は @ControllerAdvice を付けたクラスを作成します。この辺りのキーワードで検索すれば情報が見つかると思いますが、解決できないようだったら DEBUG レベルのログを有効化してエラー発生時の出力を追記してください。
